# directly initialized delegate generates ARC warning and EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash

Tags: objective-c, delegates, automatic-ref-counting

I have created a delegate object implementing the [UITextFieldDelegate](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=uitextfielddelegate&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFsQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html&ei=_JLHT8mMEcGfOrHV7OQO&usg=AFQjCNH88tX0MZc8H0Hbtwrr_re8pyDA-w&sig2=kQWlf60cyZDcVCMAlQVzDg) in its own class named `NumericTextFieldDelegate` then i have initialized the delegate in my controller in this way :

```
textFieldName.delegate = [NumericTextFieldDelegate new];
```

And i got this warning from the compiler :

```
Assigning retained object to unsafe property; object will be released after assignment
```

That means that the object will be released after the assignment and in fact when i run the application and i focus the UITextField i get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and the app crash ...

The only way to make it work that i found is creating a static variable with a factory method that dispatch the instance of the `NumericTextFieldDelegate` :

```
@interface NumericTextFieldDelegate : NSObject <UITextFieldDelegate>

+(NumericTextFieldDelegate *) getDelegate;

@end

@implementation NumericTextFieldDelegate

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSString *resultingString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange: range withString: string];

    // This allows backspace
    if ([resultingString length] == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    NSInteger holder;
    NSScanner *scan = [NSScanner scannerWithString: resultingString];

    return [scan scanInteger: &holder] && [scan isAtEnd];
}

+(NumericTextFieldDelegate *) getDelegate {
    static NumericTextFieldDelegate *del;
    @synchronized(del) {
        if(del == nil)
            del = [NumericTextFieldDelegate new];
    }
    return del;
}

@end
```

And then when i assign the delegate in this way :

```
textFieldName.delegate = [NumericTextFieldDelegate getDelegate];
```

everything works well, but my question is :

**Why can't i simply assign an anonymous new instance of the class ?** 
Why the object is automatically released after the assignment ?

**Why do i need this workaround ?**

Thanks.

Comment: It is a UITextField, not custom .

Comment: Methods should not be prefixed with `get` unless they are of a very specific type (which this one isn't).

Comment: @bbum i have inherited the get prefix from Java :-) Thanks for the tip

Comment: Lots of people have (I spent quite a bit of time in Java, but -- oddly -- working largely with ObjC derived APIs in WebObjects);  it isn't *that* big of a deal, but it'll help in the long run when your code works/acts/looks just like the system's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Inaziger analysis. The delegate of UITextField instance is a kind of weak reference. It does not hold the delegate assigned to it. According ARC, the delegate will be nil is no one hold a reference to it. Therefore, it will be up to assigner to keep it so the delegate will be called. You code prior workaround is something like this:

```
- (void) somemethod {
...
id<UITextFieldDelegate> tempDelegate = [NumericTextFieldDelegate new];
textFieldName.delegate = tempDelegate;
...
}
```

the instance of textFieldName got a reference to a delegate created locally in somethod. ARC will set temDelegate to nil after the method call. However, the text field's delegate still holds the a pointer to memory assigned to, which is released by ARC afterwards. That's why you got the bad memory access crash.

By keeping the del as static var in your class, it will be kept during your app run cycle as long as you have not set it to nil. I think it is better to keep the static del as a class level member and to provide a setter so that you should remember to release it. Something like:

```
// in interface definition
+(NumericTextFieldDelegate *) getDelegate;
+(void) setDelegate:(id)newDel;

// in implementation
static NumericTextFieldDelegate* del;

+(NumericTextFieldDelegate *) getDelegate {
  @synchronized(del) {
    if(del == nil)
      del = [NumericTextFieldDelegate new];
    }
  return del;
}

+(void) setDelegate:(id)newDel {
   del = newDel;
}
```

By the way, you can also keep your prior workaround codes as they are. You can keep the delegate in the class of text field as a class member variable or property.

```
@interface myTextFieldContainer () {
@proerpty (strong) id<UITextFieldDelegate> delHolder;
...
}

@implementaion myTextFieldContainer {
@sythysis delHolder = _delHodler;
...
self.delHolder = [NumericTextFieldDelegate new];
textFieldName.delegate = self.delHolder;
```

The benefit of above strategy is that you would not worry about release the delegate when your view controller is gone.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, delegates in Cocoa (Touch) are normally unretained. This prevents retain cycles. But this also means that something else needs to keep a reference to the object in order to release it when you are done with it — otherwise the object is just leaked. That's just the way the delegate relationship works in this pattern.

The reason your `getDelegate` method works is because a reference to the delegate is stored in the static variable `del`, which keeps ARC from releasing the object.

Comment: Yes, i know because it works ... I have wrote the workaround by myself. What i can't understand is Why if in ARC i can't retain the object that kind of assignment doesn't work ...

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't i simply assign an anonymous new instance of the class ? Why the object is automatically released after the assignment ?
>
> Why do i need this workaround ?

You can assign a new instance of the class. But it gets immediately released because it has no strong reference - only a weak one (unsafe unretained) by textfield.delegate which is to prevent retain cycles as already mentioned. And thats exactly what the warning is telling you.
I wouldn't use this singleton-like pattern however. Simply add a strong property for your delegate object and assign that property value as delegate of your textfield.

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) MyDelegateObject delegateObject;

Self.delegateObject = [MyDelegateObject new];
Textfield.delegate = self.delegateObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the "why" is because the `UITextField` property `delegate` is declared as:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UITextFieldDelegate> delegate
```

(See the [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html).)

The declared property `assign` means That the "setter uses simple assignment" and therefore doesn't implement any memory management features such as retain (or release when it is unassigned). (See [The Objective-C Programming Language, Declared Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html))

Comment: Yes, but Why ARC doesn't "understand" this ? Why i have to workaround ?

Comment: It does understand it, but is giving you the exact results that were requested.  It figures that it probably isn't what you **want** though, so gives you a warning.  The better question would be "Why does Apple use assign for their delegates?". This has to do with avoiding retain cycles, I would venture to guess.